# Facebook like button popup gateway for facebook pages

Tags: facebook, iframe, xfbml

I was wondering how do they create the page on facebook with like button as a gateway to enter and browse through the page...

Here is the one example....
http://www.facebook.com/Diesel?sk=app_168523776552050

I know how to create page in iframe and put in in facebook but I dont know how they show this popup and how do they show it for non fan visitors.

Please enlighten me with your ideas and works.....

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple "Fan Gate", and on the none-fan version they show the normal like button via the url of the page.

A simple way to build a fan gate yourself is described here: http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php

The like button:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/diesel" send="true" width="450"
show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Yeah I got it, but what about that lightbox kind of effect? How can I get that with like button?

Comment: as with every other lightbox effect. html and css.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. authenticate your application and get an access token
2. use access token to authenticate your user and to get a 'signed request' from FB.
3. 'signed request' will tell you whether the user is fan or not
4. write some code:  if (user is fan) { show content for fans }
                     else { show content for visitors }

Nothing happens without the 'signed request'.  Works in PHP and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the 'signed_request' parameter from Facebook. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/

Each signed request contains a '**page**' key with a '**liked**' subkey whose value is a bool of whether the page has been liked.

Display the banner depending on the value of that bool.

Note that only the Page Tab view has a like button on it. The Canvas App does not have a like button surrounding it.